# Problem defining a function via Step function and Dirac's Delta

Tags: calculus, derivatives, dirac-delta

**First:** I know Dirac's Delta isn't a function and hence shouldn't be treated like one. But this arose in a physics textbook so I'm looking for an answer that oversees that.

Consider the following function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \cos x , \quad \textrm{if} \quad  -\pi/2 < x < \pi/2 \\
0, \quad \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
And I want $f''(x)$. So I can just differentiate two times directly, to obtain:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -\cos x , \quad \textrm{if} \quad  -\pi/2 < x < \pi/2 \\
0, \quad \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
However, if I decide to write:
$$f(x) = H(-\pi/2)\cos x - H(\pi/2)\cos x$$
($H(x)$ stands for Heaviside's step function). 
I can't differentiate twice. Moreover, if I decide to write:
$$f'(x) = - H(-\pi/2)\sin x + H(\pi/2)\sin x$$
I'll obtain:
$$f''(x) = -\delta(-\pi/2)\cos x + \delta(\pi/2)\cos x$$ 
However
$$\int f''(x) dx = - \cos(-\pi/2) + \cos (\pi/2) = 0$$
Which also doesn't make sense. Now, for another problem (where the discotinuity at the first derivative occured in a point where $f(x) \neq 0$) the author used Dirac's Delta and Heaviside to obtain the derivative. But here he just claims that since $f(x) = f''(x)  = 0$ at the end points, we shouldn't worry about the deltas and just differentiate directly (as I did) to obtain the correct expression. My question comes from the fact that I can seemingly define the function and it's first derivative in the three ways I did, and the three ways give me different expressions for the second derivative. Why?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $H(\pi/2)$? To me, this means the value of the Heaviside step function evaluated at $\pi/2$. In that case, it's just a constant, and shouldn't change under differentiation; moreover, your expression for $f$ reduces to $f(x) = -\cos x$, which isn't right. Did you instead mean $H(x-\pi/2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H(\frac{\pi}{2})$ does not depend on $x$. It is not a function of $x$. It is a constant. And it should not become $\delta$ when taking the second derivative.

It also mean that your definition of $f$ is incorrect. Likely you intended

$$f(x) = H(x + \frac{\pi}{2}) \cos x - H(x - \frac{\pi}{2}) \cos x$$

Now you need to differentiate it.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake writing the question, thank you, I'll correct it. But I can't see how this answer actually answers my question. Could you please elaborate? How can I differentiate twice a Heaviside function?